# How do I plot a function along a specified contour of parameters?

Tags: plotting

I have a scalar function (actually, a set of eigenvalues) which takes two parameters, say $f(x,y)$. I would like to make a 2D plot of this function for a continuous, closed loop of parameter values in the shape of a square, which would consist of four line segments connecting the four corners as
$$(x(t),y(t)) = (0,0)\rightarrow(1,0)\rightarrow(1,1)\rightarrow(0,1)\rightarrow(0,0)$$
You can equivalently think of making a 3D plot of this function and tracing its value along a closed contour of parameters and plotting only this "cross section" of the function. I'm not sure how this can be implemented in Mathematica.

Comment: Why not use `Plot3D`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a function you want to plot

```
f[x_, y_] := Cos[x] + Sin[y]
```

Interpolate over the path

```
p = Interpolation[{{0, {0, 0}}, {1, {0, 1}}, {2, {1, 1}}, {3, {1, 
     0}}, {4, {0, 0}}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

Plot

```
Plot[f @@ p[t], {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

Improved plot

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}};
dts = Norm /@ Differences[pts];
adts = Join[{0}, Accumulate[dts]];
path = Transpose[{adts, pts}];
p = Interpolation[path, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Plot[f @@ p[t], {t, 0, 4}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {path, None}}, 
 GridLines -> {Accumulate[dts], None}, 
 PlotTheme -> {"Monochrome", "Frame"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

- **3D**

```
f[x_, y_] = 5 x*Sin[3 x*y] + Cos[8 x] + 2 + Sin[10 y];
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
 PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"]
```

[image]

- **2D**

```
f[x_, y_] = 5 x*Sin[3 x*y] + Cos[8 x] + 2 + Sin[10 y];
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};
lines = Partition[pts, 2, 1, 1];
plots = Table[
   Plot[f @@ ((1 - t)*line[[1]] + t*line[[2]]), {t, 0, 1}], {line, 
    lines}];
GraphicsGrid[Partition[plots, 2, 2]]
```

[image]